# SQl Server Bulk Insert Permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, bulkinsert

Using: SQL server 2019 (15.0.40832.2)

I am currently experiencing import issues when trying to bulk insert a file into a table.  The code I have works fine when executed as SA, but not when executed as a non admin user.

From checking existing post here I have ensured the following has already been done:

- xp_cmdshell_proxy_account is configured.
- file is accessable to the account above. (tested see below)
- Non SA account has been added to the bulk admin server role

  ALTER SERVER ROLE bulkadmin ADD MEMBER [MyNonSaUser] -- Run on master
- Insert permission has been granted

  GRANT INSERT TO [MyNonSaUser] -- Run on destination db and master
- Bulk operations specifically granted to the user in addition to the role above.

  GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO [MyNonSaUser] -- Run on master

However I am still getting the error:

```
You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.
```

My code for testing the file access is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp;

CREATE TABLE #Temp ( Field1           NVARCHAR(4000)
,                    Field2           NVARCHAR(4000));

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'TYPE FilePathAndFileName.dat' 
-- Works as expected

BULK INSERT #Temp FROM 'FilePathAndFileName.dat'
WITH ( DATAFILETYPE = 'char' , FIRSTROW = 1 , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' , FIELDTERMINATOR = '|' , CODEPAGE = 'ACP' ); 
-- Works as expected

SELECT  *  FROM  #Temp;
TRUNCATE TABLE #Temp

EXECUTE AS USER = 'MyNonSaUser';

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'TYPE FilePathAndFileName.dat' 
-- Works as expected

BULK INSERT #Temp FROM 'FilePathAndFileName.dat'
WITH ( DATAFILETYPE = 'char' , FIRSTROW = 1 , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' , FIELDTERMINATOR = '|' , CODEPAGE = 'ACP' ); 
-- Fails with error above

SELECT  *  FROM  #Temp;
REVERT;
```

Any advice on how to procede from here, or any further things to check would be greatfully received.

Comment: `#Temp` was created by the other user, does this user need permissions? Does it work when `#Temp` is created in a single batch by this user?

Comment: Potential flaw in your test: Temp tables reside in the tempdb. Have you granted appropriate permissions to the tempdb? Alternatively, create a throw-away table in the permissioned database upon which you can test.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback here,  unfortunately no, thats not the issue.  The table permissions are not the cause, rather that the NonSaUser believes it does not have permission when I believe it has been granted.